# Extracting pedestrian step duration from video

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, frames, stride

I have a front view pedestrian surveillance video of about 15 seconds. The video looks a bit like the picture bellow. I want to estimate the number of frames needed by a pedestrian to complete one step.

Are there any papers available describing techniques that would perform that?
[frontal view detected pedestrian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVTkV.jpg)